# Decimals counter React + JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, counter

so i created a counter from 0 to given number, but i have problems with decimals. i mean - for example - it's supposed to be counted from 0 to 4.5, but it stops at 4.1, it's counting from 0 to 5.7 (0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ..... 5.7), but it stops at 5.1 etc. and i really can't figure out where is the mistake in the code. Maybe someone can help?

the part of the code:

```
if (!this.valueCount){
      this.value = 0;
      let valueInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.value === this.value1){
          clearInterval(valueInterval);
          this.valueCount = false;
        } else if (this.value < this.value1){
          this.value++;
          this.valueCount = true;
        } else {
          this.value--;
          this.valueCount = true;
        }
        this.value =+ (this.value + 0.1).toFixed(1);
        this.base.querySelector('#value .values').innerHTML = this.value;
      }, 50);
```

Comment: because you use integers

Comment: @AshKander can you explain this in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing `value` the wrong way, increment it by `0.1` like this :

```js
let value = 0,
    value1 = 4.5;
    
let valueInterval = setInterval(() => {
  if (value === value1) {
    clearInterval(valueInterval);
  } else if (value < value1) {
    value += 0.1;
  } else {
    value -= 0.1;
  }
  
  console.log(value.toFixed(1));
}, 500);
```

Comment: I think he/she is talking about this line: `this.value =+ (this.value + 0.1).toFixed(1);`

Comment: @FiriceNguyen exactly, i mean this line which you mentioned in the comment. unfortunately the solution posted by Nathan P. doesn't work in my case

Comment: @petlet What doesn't work ? I may have misunderstood your problem

Comment: @SixthEngineer i tried to increment it like you posted: += 0.1 or -= 0.1, but it's not working. the problem is that each number which i enter as a 'target' number till which it should be counted (for example 5.7) - it stops counting at 5.1, always it stops counting at something point 1 (x.1). i guess the mistake is somewhere in this line of my code: this.value =+ (this.value + 0.1).toFixed(1);

Comment: @petlet Yes it is this line the problem, use `console.log(this.value)` to see it doesn't act like you want. Use `+= 0.1` and `-= 0.1` without this line and it'll run fine.

Comment: @NathanP. even though i added += 0.1 and -= 0.1 and deleted this line this.value =+ (this.value + 0.1).toFixed(1); - it still doesn't work